# How to get existing Outlook form items

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

In my VSTO Outlook 2013 addin I need show new form near already existing elements (like button "New Email"). Previous searches led me to the fact that it is necessary to calculate the position of the main window on the screen and the position of the desired element inside the form. But how to get these positions - I must use winapi or something else?

Comment: @mjwills, sorry my fault - `existing`

Comment: You may wish to edit your title.

Answer (score 0):

You Ribbon XML must specify `insertBeforeMso` or `insertAfterMso` to specify the position of your button relative to an existing built-in button.